# How can i convert a database .mdf and .ldf files into an excel file in asp.Net / C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, excel

I have an application that needs to upload .mdf and .ldf files and convert them into an excel file in the website and then allow them to be downloaded on the client computer. I have no idea how to start and what to do?

Can someone give me some ideas about how to convert a database in .mdf and .ldf files into excel file

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't simple Convert the file.

You should go through these steps:

> - Create a connection to your database
> - Select all Rows und Columns you need from you tables in the database
>       This should helpe you: [ADO.Net](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/4278/using-adonet-with-sql-server/)
> - Create a new Excel-Sheet (Take a look at Open XML)
>       This should heklp you: [Create Excel-Sheet](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/371203/Creating-basic-Excel-workbook-with-Open-XML)
> - Fill you Excel-Sheet with the selected datas from your Database
> - Save the Excel Sheet
> - Now you are ready!

Answer (score 0):

Have a read of [this document which describes - How to import data from Microsoft SQL Server into Microsoft Excel](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306125)

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to be able to do this, for the simple reason that even after you upload the files you're not going to be able to attach them to the SQL server instance to query them (and then follow the process suggested by @BendEg).

Edit:

Seems I wasn't quite correct if you look at this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264564.aspx#sqlexpuser_topic2) you can attach to a uploaded database by specifying the `AttachDbFilename` in the connection string.

Comment: but i am using asp.net/C# first time. so i have no more idea about this. so please have some code which help me for attached file. so please give me that

Answer (score 0):

Its easy just do the following
Right click your database-->GO to tasks-->Go to import data